# Create a new header file in Visual Studio 2019 with C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, header-files

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and am trying to create a header file, I cannot seem to figure out how to though. I have seen many tutorials which simply create a new item and select the header file template. I have searched everywhere in Visual Studio and don't see anyway to make a header file. Is there a way to do this or is it through some extension and if so which one?

I tried using the solution explorer extension to create a header file as I had seen many videos do but when I create a new folder to create the header in I simply get an error message for that extension.

Comment: Did you try right clicking on the header file folder in the solution explorer and choosing add new item?

Comment: If you are really asking that sort of question, you should become familiar with basic menu and toolbar Windows stuff before any programming attempt. Menu "File" => "New" => "File" should be more than obvious.

Comment: Have you selected C++ when you have installed Visual Studio? Run the installer again and add missing features. As described, the tutorial seems correct. Maybe, you have selected C# or some other language instead. Also, do you have a C++ project? You cannot add a C++ file in a C# project for example.

Answer (score 1):

To create a header file for a new class, right-click to open the shortcut menu for the MathLibrary project in Solution Explorer, and then choose Add > New Item. In the Add New Item dialog box, select Visual C++ > Code. In the center pane, select Header File (. h).

Answer (score 0):

Open visual studio from the left select new project a dialogue box appears on the dialogue box select empty project (don't select console application) then press OK a blank visual screen will appear now on the right side you will see a box named solution explorer(if you don't find it press Ctrl+Alt+l) with your project name under your project right click on header file select add then select new item a dialogue box appears with file types select header file(.h) name your header file and then press add your new header file is created

Answer (score 0):

1.Create new project
2.In Solution Explorer put in folder Header Files your Header File
3. In Resource Folder put your Resource File(library)
4.Use your library in your source file